# How to move from Ubuntu 11.04 32-bit version to 64-bit?

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 11.04 and a couple of applications. I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu as a whole. So with my home it isn't any problem; I have it on another partition.

So, how can I change the architecture without the need to install programs after installation of a 64-bit version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Consider that the programs you installed are 32-bit, but you have to install 64-bit programs on a 64-bit system (at least the package manager wants it that way). All you can do is do a fresh install of a 64-bit operating system, but keep your existing home partition (which can be done from the installer).

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers:

You cannot avoid a reinstall of the OS, however you *can* avoid having to manually select all the apps you want to install.

You can record the list of installed packages under Ubuntu, then automatically install them all after you re-installed the base system. That might make the reinstall less of a hassle.

This is explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/how-do-i-migrate-configuration-between-computers-with-different-hardware